# How to play a multiplayer team death match in MW3 indefinitely? (no scoring)

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I do not know if this is possible but I think the online team death match is too fast? The game ends every 10-20 mins when the score is reached. Is there a way or a mode that let's you play indefinitely without scoring or at least to join a game with extremely high score goals? Currently I have no choice and I am automatically joined in a random game. This is PS3 btw.

Comment: MW3 is an 'arcade-style' shooter - fast-paced, not tactical (except in a few modes), focused on constant action. For this reason, matches are shorter. Other games (like BF3) have longer games, but different play styles. Generally, you can't have the best of both worlds. The closest I think you can get in MW3 to really long games is Sabatoge (see agent's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In private matches, you can customize the rules of the game and change things such as the time limit and score limit.  However, you must then invite friends to play with you.  Private matches are just that - private, and only open to the people you invite.

If you're looking to play a game against random people on the internet, you are limited to the playlists that are available within the game.  None of the available multiplayer game modes are time-based in Modern Warfare 3.

That said, Team Deathmatch games tend to play pretty quickly, but if you just want to be playing and getting kills, you might try an "objective" game type.

For instance:

- Sabotage tends to take longer and does not have a kill limit.  The objective is to get a bomb to a bomb site, which many people ignore in favor of just killing each other.
- Kill Confirmed requires that you pick up tags in order to get credit for a kill, so there are typically more kills per round than in other "kill enemies to win" modes.
- Drop Zone also focuses more on holding a position and playing with killstreak rewards than on a specific number of kills.
- Ground War mixes several game types and has a higher score limit, so more kills are required to win, although there are typically more players.

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive answer I think I will try S&D.

Comment: S&D is probably not your best option for a long game.  While the game may take a long time that is partly because there is no respawning so the strategy tends to be more conservative.  If you die really early in a round you have to sit out the rest of the round waiting for one side to win.  Kill Confirmed is probably the best option of the suggested, Drop Zone can last a while but tends to be very grenade spam heavy and game length can be really short if one team dominates

Comment: @RobV, ah, you're quite correct, I was confusing S&D with Sabotage.  The three bomb-type games tend to blur together for me.